# Pandas Dataframe to JSON add JSON Object Name

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe that I'm converting to JSON but I'm having a hard time naming the object.  The code I have:

```
    j = (df_import.groupby(['Item', 'Subinventory', 'TransactionUnitOfMeasure', 'TransactionType', 'TransactionDate', 'TransactionSourceId', 'OrganizationName'])
    .apply(lambda x: x[['LotNumber', 'TransactionQuantity']].to_dict('records'))
    .reset_index()
    .rename(columns={0: 'lotItemLots'})
    .to_json(orient='records'))
```

The result I'm getting:

```
[
  {
    "Item": "000400MCI00099",
    "OrganizationName": "OR",
    "Subinventory": "LAB R",
    "TransactionDate": "2021-08-19 00:00:00",
    "TransactionSourceId": 3000001595xxxxx,
    "TransactionType": "Account Alias Issue",
    "TransactionUnitOfMeasure": "EA",
    "lotItemLots": [
      {
        "LotNumber": "00040I",
        "TransactionQuantity": -5
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

The result I need (the transactionLines part), but can't figure out:

```
    {
   "transactionLines":[
      {
         "Item":"000400MCI00099",
         "Subinventory":"LAB R",
         "TransactionQuantity":-5,
         "TransactionUnitOfMeasure":"EA",
         "TransactionType":"Account Alias Issue",
         "TransactionDate":"2021-08-20 00:00:00",
         "OrganizationName":"OR",
         "TransactionSourceId": 3000001595xxxxx,
         "lotItemLots":[{"LotNumber":"00040I", "TransactionQuantity":-5}]
      }
   ]
}
```

[image: Source Data from Excel]

```
Index,Item Number,5 Digit,Description,Subinventory,Lot Number,Quantity,EOM,[Qty],Transaction Type,Today's Date,Expiration Date,Source Header ID,Lot Interface Number,Transaction Source ID,TransactionType,Organization Name
1,000400MCI00099,40,ACANTHUS OAK LEAF,LAB R,00040I,-5,EA,5,Account Alias Issue,2021/08/25,2002/01/01,160200,160200,3000001595xxxxx,Account Alias Issue,OR
```

Would appreciate any guidance on how to get the transactionLines name in there.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: please add your source dataset

Comment: Added source data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would seem to me you could simply parse the json output, and then re-form it the way you want:

```
import pandas as pd
import json 

data = [{'itemID': 0, 'itemprice': 100}, {'itemID': 1, 'itemprice': 200}]
data = pd.DataFrame(data)

pd_json = data.to_json(orient='records') 

new_collection = [] # store our reformed records

# loop over parsed json, and reshape it the way we want
for record in json.loads(pd_json):
    nested = {'transactionLines': [record]} # matching specs of question
    new_collection.append(nested)
    
new_json = json.dumps(new_collection) # convert back to json str

print(new_json)
```

Which results in:

```
[
 {"transactionLines": [{"itemID": 0, "itemprice": 100}]}, 
 {"transactionLines": [{"itemID": 1, "itemprice": 200}]}
]
```

Note that of course you could probably do this in a more concise manner, without the intermediate json conversion.

Comment: Thank you!  Looping the created json and the nested line is what I was missing.